# Partition function NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, nullpointerexception

I am implementing the [Partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), you can see the return value of long(or int) in the first function is no problem.

```
public static long p(int n) {
        long[] ways = new long[n + 1];
        ways[0] = 1;
        int[] coins = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            coins[i] = i + 1;   
        for(int coin : coins) {
            for(int j = coin; j <= n; j++) {
                ways[j] += ways[j - coin];
            }
        }
        return ways[n];
    }
```

it returns the right value. But when I implemented it with BigInteger value(when the input n is very big, the return value is beyoun the range of Long), it turn out to be wrong, which has `java.lang.NullPointerException.` I can't find where I did incorrectedly. The ***function with bug*** is below:

```
    public static BigInteger p(int n) {
            BigInteger[] ways = new BigInteger[n + 1];
//initial the BigInteger[] ways------> Additional question: Is it necessary?
            ways[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                ways[i] = BigInteger.ONE; // --update-- Here should be initialed with BigInteger.ZERO, not ONE!
            int[] coins = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                coins[i] = i + 1;
            for(int coin : coins) {
                for(int j = coin; j <= n; j++) {
                    BigInteger temp = ways[j].add(ways[j - coin]);
                    ways[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            return ways[n];
        }
```

Any reply will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ways-array has the size of n+1. In your for-loop you go from i = 1 < n. shouldn't it be < n+1?

Instead of

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        ways[i] = BigInteger.ONE;
```

you should do

```
for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
        ways[i] = BigInteger.ONE;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to change n to n+1 in for loop:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        ways[i] = BigInteger.ONE;
```

Comment: Oh, my God! I did such stupid thing! Got it! Thank you very much!